# How to calculate joint area of circles defined at each point on a continuous curve

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, area

Given a curve c (x(s),y(s)) in a 2D space (shown in red)
and a radius function r(s) which gives the radius of a circle at that point.

The red curve c(s) thus is the union of all centers of the circles.

What would be the area of the union of all the circles on the curve.

[image]

Comment: So the radius changes with the parameter s ? (not like your picture where r(s) seems constant)

Comment: Yes it does. In th picture it stays constant indeed.  A first subproblem might be to solve it for constant radius.

Comment: Are you looking for analytical or nummerical solution?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk . In the first place I'm looking for an analytical equation. But any information of a numerical procedure would be extremely helpful (for practical purposes i'll need it eventually ...)

Comment: Possible overlap when c changes direction in which it's moving make it quite hard to come up with a analytical derivation. For numeric's I'll define a grid, take dS and every step simply count points inside of circle around c($s_0$ + n dS) with radius r($s_0$ + n dS) that haven't been counted before.

Comment: If 1) $r(s) = r$ is constant, 2) $r$ is  smaller than the radius of curvature of the base curve for all $s$ and 3) circles centered at different $c(s_1)$ and $c(s_2)$ don't intersect when $s_1$ is far away from $s_2$, then the area is $\pi r^2 + 2r L$ where $L$ is the length of base curve. I believe this has been first worked out by Hotelling (in 1939?) and ultimately lead Weyl to develop his formula for volume of tubes.